# which user/group do update?

Tags: 18.04, updates

I have two main user on my ubuntu 18.04. One I use for everyday life, and the other for job.

However check for update is only done for latter one (job user), not for the former (everyday).

I want the other way round (so that I don't get annoyed when switching to job user).

- in which group must I put everday user ?
- in which file is check for update trigerred ?

Edit:

- I want check triggered by everyday user.
- currently, check is done at login time with my job user (and once a week if session run for long).

Comment: Is the check done automatically and you don't want that?
Do you want the check to only happen in the everyday user? Or you don't need the check at all?

Comment: I want check trigerred by everyday user. I create it in a second time, my job user was specified in OS installation.

Comment: What do you do as (job user) today to check for update .. exact commands pls. And when you do the same on (every day user) what is the result ?

Comment: Your (job user) is defined as an administrator and (everyday user) is normal user. From the  (job user) account, give admin privilege to  (everyday user). Then from (everyday user) account switch  (job user) to normal account.